# Tax miscalculation for partial creditmemo

Tags: core, orders

We are working on a project for a customer that is running on Magento Community Edition 1.7.0.1.

We have encountered the following issue:

When we create a partial credit memo the recalculation of the tax amount is done properly. (*=Total Tax field*)

As soon as we click on the *Total Tax field* when viewing the details of the partial credit memo we just created the details pop out. (Default Magento behavior).

The calculation of the tax rate is wrong:

[image]

As you can see the "Total TVA" (=Total Tax) is correct but the detailed tax rate "TVA (21%)" is not correct.

**The given amount next to "TVA (21%)" matches the total tax amount of the complete order we created.**

Basically, it means that this isn't recalculated properly... Do any of you also have this issue? Could it be a Magento bug? Any idea what the cleanest way would be to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to solve this by editing app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/tax/order/tax.phtml:

Look for the following:

```
<?php
    $percent    = $info['percent'];
    $amount     = $info['amount'];
    $rates      = $info['rates'];
    $isFirst    = 1;
?>
```

and replace it with:

```
<?php
    $percent    = $info['percent'];
    $amount     = $_source->getTaxAmount();
    $rates      = $info['rates'];
    $isFirst    = 1;
?>
```